# Customize start menu Microsoft Office icons

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, icons

I am trying to customize icons on the taskbar and start menu in Windows 10.
I tried to do this first through changing icons on the shortcuts at

*C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs*

This changed icons of most applications, but not Microsoft Office.

Next, I tried to make new shortcuts for all the programs I wanted to customize the icons for. I placed them all in a folder on the desktop, and pinned those shortcuts to the start and taskbar. However, Office start icons still remained the original.

**How can you change Microsoft Office icons on start menu in Windows 10?**

Comment: Did you delete or alter the folder containing your custom icons? Because icon information isn't stored anywhere else. If you set a custom icon, Windows expects that path to still be valid at reboot.

Comment: I realized that there was a program altering taskbar jumplists... removing this stoppd taskbar icons from reverting. As for Office icons in the start menu, nothing has changed yet. no matter what I do, they are still default icons

Comment: Try to move those shortcuts from that start menu folder. Then reboot and replace those as previous. See if any change.

Comment: Removing shortcuts from the start menu folder prohibited me from pinning Office programs on the start menu. I don't know why, but I can not think of a workaround for this problem.